# Making Integral Stationary

Tags: calculus

We want to write and solve the Euler equation to make the integral stationary.

let $ I = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} e^x\sqrt {1+y'^2} $.

so $ F(x,y,y') = e^x\sqrt {1+y'^2} $.

we find $ F_{y'} =  \frac{e^xy'}{2\sqrt{1+y'^2}}$ and $ F_{y}= 0 $.

Now we use the Euler-Lagrange equation to find y.

$$ \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}-\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = 0 $$

This gives $$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'} = 0 $$

$$\implies\frac{d}{dx}{\frac{e^xy'}{2\sqrt{1+y'^2}}} = 0.$$

Now we integrate to get

$$\frac{e^xy'}{2\sqrt{1+y'^2}} = c_1$$ where $c_1$ is a constant of integration.

Now we wish to solve for $y'$ to get to $y$. How do we do this?

Comment: Try this. It should simplify your problem quite a bit. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BeltramiIdentity.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last equation is reduced to

$${{\rm e}^{x}}{\frac {d}{dx}}y \left( x \right) =2\,c_{{1}}\sqrt {1+
 \left( {\frac {d}{dx}}y \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}}
$$

Then you have

$$\left( {\frac {d}{dx}}y \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}{{\rm e}^{2\,x}}=4\,{c_{{1}}}^{2} \left( 1+ \left( {\frac {d}{dx}}y \left( x \right) 
 \right) ^{2} \right) 
$$

From this last equation you derive that
$$\left( {\frac {d}{dx}}y \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}={\frac {4{c_{{1}}}^{2}}{{{\rm e}^{2\,x}}-4\,{c_{{1}}}^{2}}}
$$

It is to say

$${\frac {d}{dx}}y \left( x \right) ={\frac {2c_{{1}}}{\sqrt {{{\rm e}
^{2\,x}}-4\,{c_{{1}}}^{2}}}}
$$

Making the integration you obtain

$$y \left( x \right) =\arctan \left( {\frac {\sqrt {{{\rm e}^{2\,x}
}-4\,{c_{{1}}}^{2}}}{2c_{{1}}}} \right) +{\it c_2}
$$

Do you agree?